# cannot connect to mariadb server remotely

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

When my flask app tries to connect remotely to the server named ceres I get error saying

```
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ceres.local' (65)")
```

so I checked `my.cnf` file shown below

```
ciasto@ceres:/etc/mysql $ cat my.cnf
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

[mysqld]
#skip-networking

#bind-address = <some ip-address>

# Fine Tuning

max_allowed_packet      = 128M

wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
```

bind-address is commented which I believe it is open ago accept all remote connections but still my app cannot connect to mariadb running mysql on remote machine .

Also after a day long gap between application run I always get error `MySQL server has gone away.`

Comment: @yip102011 , I don't think so.

Comment: It is same error no. 2003. Unless you already try those four solution in that post and post the result here. It is duplicated question

Comment: I have triedd all the options. The different part is I am on osx and mariadb is running on raspbian

Comment: I think you need to provide more information for people to help you. Like how you try connection to DB, what command you are using? What is DB server firewall port status? What is the db user permission?

Comment: I can connect to remote MySQL from terminal of my MacBook